# Spotlight Query Exclude Specific Folder(s)

Tags: mac, search, finder, spotlight

I want to exclude specific folders from a spotlight query. I do **NOT** want to exclude them from indexing in general -- I just want to exclude them from my current query. I know how to add exclusion clauses to my queries (hold down alt/option and then click the ellipses and then click 'none'), however I don't know the field I'm supposed to choose. Is it 'Location,' 'URL,' 'Name'? I even tried using the `mdls` command on an example file in the folder I'm trying to exclude but I still don't know the name of the field that holds the file's path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *URL* and e.g. `file:///Users/danielbeck/*` to exclude all items in my home directory, using `*` as wildcard operator.

Based on the description, I think *Location* refers to physical location e.g. in Photo metadata.

*Name* is just the file name itself, not the path.